# TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S23') dtype('S23') dtype('S23')

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe `df` and I want to print out a list of variables along with types and the number of missing fields (NaN, NA).

```
def var_desc(df,dt):
    print('============================================')
    for c in df.columns:
        if df[c].dtype==dt:
            e = sum(pd.isnull(df[c]))
            print(c+' : '+dt+' | '+e)
    print('============================================') 

var_desc(df,"object")
var_desc(df,"int64")
```

There is some issue with the line `e = sum(pd.isnull(df[c]))`. It gives the following error:

`TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S23') dtype('S23') dtype('S23')`

How to fix it?

Comment: You could try `e = df[c].isnull().sum()`.

Comment: @IanS: It gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
count_nan = len(df) - df.count()
```

As [count](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) is returning the non-NA/null, this way you can reach the number of the non None records.

> DataFrame.count(axis=0, level=None, numeric_only=False)[source]¶
>
> Return Series with number of non-NA/null observations over requested
> axis. Works with non-floating point data as well (detects NaN and
> None)

Comment: I get this error: /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in <lambda>(x, y)
     68         add=arith_method(operator.add, names('add'), op('+'),
     69                          default_axis=default_axis),
---> 70         radd=arith_method(lambda x, y: y + x, names('radd'), op('+'),
     71                           default_axis=default_axis),
     72         sub=arith_method(operator.sub, names('sub'), op('-'),

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S24') dtype('S24') dtype('S24')

Comment: The error is indeed triggered by `print(c+' : '+dt+' | '+count_nan)`. If I do `print(c+' : '+dt)`, then it runs well. So, some issue with printing out. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it myself: `count_nan = str(len(df) - df.count())
            print(c+' : '+dt+' | '+count_nan)`